# Microsoft Access Database connect to php

Tags: php, odbc, ms-access-2007

My system OS is 64-bit. Ms Access 2007 is 32 bit. I have connect with PHP.
PHP file give following error:

> "Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect in C:\wamp\www\PI\Connection.php on line 3"

Connection.php

```
<?php

$con = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)};Dbq=PIInstitute","","");

if($con){
    echo "Connected";

}else{

    echo "Failed";
}
?>
```

Comment: Maybe this post can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222684/connecting-to-ms-access-2007-using-odbc-connect-error-in-driver

Comment: its give error could not find driver

Comment: Access bitness doesn't matter. PHP bitness dictates ODBC driver bitness. Usually best to `odbc_connect("DSN=dsn-name","uid","pwd")` with known-working DSN.

Comment: this is give above error

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a duplicate of:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48339856/warning-odbc-connect-sql-error-microsoftodbc-driver-manager-data-source

Comment: yes,but i have need perfect answer and solve my problem.